# Code unreachable in while and if statements

Tags: java

Code below fails to compile since `x=3` is unreachable

```
while (false) { x=3; }
```

But why `for( int i = 0; i< 0; i++) {x = 3;}` compiles fine? In this code `x=3` is also unreachable.

Comment: Of course it is unreachable, try while (true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [JLS 14.21, Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

> The contained statement [in a while loop] is reachable iff the while statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression whose value is false.

`false` is a constant expression whose value is `false`, so `x=3;` is unreachable.

> The contained statement [in a basic for loop] is reachable iff the for statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression whose value is false.

`i<0` isn't a constant expression, so the contained statement is considered reachable, even if it is not *actually* reachable.

Comment: explained nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

The while statement can be proven unreachable in compilation time, whereas the for statement needs to be checked in running time to find it unreachable.

If you try this

```
int i = 0;
while(i>1) { i = 4; }
```

The code will compile just fine.